# urlrewritefilter not redirecting

Tags: java, url-rewriting, xml-parsing, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to implement what seems like a very simple redirect with urlrewritefilter as follows but it is not redirecting.

```
<rule> 
<from>/?industry_id=22</from> 
<to type="permanent-redirect">/industry/22/publishing</to> 
</rule>
```

Other rules work just fine. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the full URL that is not redirecting?  Also, are you sure that another rule above this is not being caught?

Comment: It is http://domain.com/?industry_id=22. It is only on my localhost now so I can't give you a live URL. I put it as the first rule to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: I thought maybe I needed to break the parameter out into a condition so I tried this

`<rule> 
<condition type="query-string">industry_id=22</condition>
<from>/</from>
<to type="permanent-redirect">/industry/22/publishing</to> 
</rule>  `

Also doesn't work.

Comment: I got the same problem and resolved it using

  `<rule>  <condition type="parameter" name="fruit"></condition> <from>/</from> <to type="permanent-redirect">/myUrl/%{parameter:fruit}</to> </rule>`

which worked fine.
The above code helps @Jim.
But the parameter name isn't taking any special characters. Throwinng
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - %%7
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your "From" is being interpreted as a regex. Try escaping the special characters, like:

```
<rule>
  <from>/\?industry_id\=22</from>
  <to type="permanent-redirect">/industry/22/publishing</to>
</rule>
```

And let us know if it worked! :)